# Docker build context: file not found in build context. How to solve?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I would like to build a new image, using my dockerfile located in the folder 'docker', which contains other three files, one of those is package.json.
In my docker file I use the command 'COPY package.json .', but I received the error:
**COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat json/package.json: file does not exist**.

FROM node:alpine as opsweb-front-end-builder

RUN mkdir /ng-app

WORKDIR /ng-app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

ecc ecc.

Given that I am not excluding anything with the .dockerignore, what can be the issue?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line; `RUN ls` to see which files are present at the time of building. If the files are not present include them in the directory. If you are sure that they are present, as the error message indicates; you might add `*.json` to your `.dockerignore` file.

Edit; You are changing your working directory but you have to copy the file first. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the useful comment!
Still it is a bit weird to me, since I move the .json file in the directory, and when I access the VM and perform ls I can clearly see it, but when I use RUN ls, I can't anymore, I can only see the folders, not the individual files.

Comment: I would add `RUN ls` to the every line of the Dockerfile. I know it sounds silly but have you tried copying other 2 files? You can also build the image, start it and then "connect" to the container by running `docker exec -ti container_name sh`. Also, make sure it works without creating a new directory and directly running `RUN npm install`.

Comment: The problematic thing might be that I run the docker build command on a remote VM, using :
cat ./Dockerfile | ssh proba3gsms 'docker build --progress=plain -t hasbullion -'
So maybe this is the source of the problem, but I am pretty sure this can be done

Comment: I don't think that can cause any problems like this. Last thing that comes to my mind is change to `COPY ../package.json .` . But the first part is absolute path, so again I'm not sure.

Comment: I solved this issue by moving the files to the VM, an run docker build locally. It doesn't make any sense, but now Docker is able to recognize the build context correctly

Comment: Ah, so the files were on your local machine and your were trying to build remotely?

Comment: Exactly, I thought it was possible to do, but it seems like it's not